# delete statement that contains join

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, duplicates, sql-delete

i found duplicate records in my database from a year ago. i'm trying to clean them up i found all ID's i need to remove using:

```sql
select id
from impWthrDta as a
right join (
    SELECT dte, rltn
    FROM impWthrDta 
    GROUP BY dte, rltn
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) as b
on a.dte = b.dte
and a.rltn = b.rltn
where id >= '0'
order by a.rltn, a.dte
```

why can i not simply replace

```sql
select *
```

with

```sql
delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Just add the DELETE statement and use your query as a filter for the IDs:

```
DELETE FROM WhateverTable
WHERE ID IN 
(select id
from impWthrDta as a
right join (
    SELECT dte, rltn
    FROM impWthrDta 
    GROUP BY dte, rltn
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) as b
on a.dte = b.dte
and a.rltn = b.rltn
where id >= '0')
```

Comment: i thought i tried this 3 times, but trying it again worked. thanks!